# an i/o error while sending to backend, java.net.socketexception read timeout

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, etl, pentaho

i wanted to ask that i tried to load data to Postgresql13 with using ETL Tools ,it is Pentaho in my case.. And while my "transformation" in pentaho running, suddenly i got

```
"An I/O error occured while sending to the backend."
java.net.socketexception read timeout
```

I have read many discussions about it and most of them said it is not from the ETL Tools Error, more like of Postgresql Error. Has someone experiencing this ? And have anyone solved it yet? Btw i'm trying to load from

Postgresql11(data source)=>Postgresql13(destination)

The Job has many merge join

[image: pentaho]

Comment: The query took longer than `socketTimeout`. Check you db connection settings and also make sure the batch does not take longer than that.

Comment: where can i check the socketTimeout time? Because if that's the problem, maybe i needed to increase it?

Comment: Might be in the connection config, if not it's using the default. You should check your query also as it might be taking more than that.

Comment: I've read it here `https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/216108-Time-Out-Issue-org-postgresql-util-PSQLException-An-I-O-error-occurred-while-sendi/` 
It said that to increase the timeout like in here :`https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/connect.html`
I don't really understand where to change it ? Is it in the jdbc file?